# Prometheus not starting

Tags: prometheus

There was some storage space added to a bastion host where Prometheus is running, pulling metrics from 6 Cassandra nodes. Since then Prometheus is not starting. In the error message it says:

> Opening storage failed open
>   /data/prometheus/01D8GR67YKKZM51V4EPEQ4XH9J/meta.json: permission
>   denied

But as you can see below, Prometheus is being started with `sudo` and the file is set to `ec2-user`.
I suppose you'll need more info to help me, but I'm not that proficient with Prometheus, so let me know what other info might be useful to debug this, and I'll update the post.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `ls` you can see the configuration file is owned by *ec2-user*, who is the only one that has any type of access  (`rw-------`), while the service is running as *prometheus* user.

Try fixing either the ownership or the permissions of the file.

Comment: Doh! Don't you just hate when it's a simple thing, right in front of you and you miss it? :) thanks for the heads up